# How to minimize number of API calls for an autocomplete field in React

Tags: reactjs

I am creating a simple flight search website in React. I want the user to be able to search a destination (i.e. Boston), and as they are typing it in have location suggestions appear that they can then select. For this purpose I am using an autocomplete API, which returns a maximum of 5 location objects depending on the current search.

The problem is that my implementation makes a ton of API calls, which with real users would become expensive quickly. Right now I make a call to the API every time the user inputs a keystroke using the onChange() function in a form input field. Is this the standard for autocomplete APIs, or is there a way to minimize the number of API calls made?

I am currently using a button in order to fetch info after the user has inputted their destination, as the autocomplete API calls are too expensive.

Comment: you should use debounce as it is explain in this [article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/implement-search-box-with-debounce-in-javascript/). The idea is to make a http call only after some amount of time without any new change event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `debounce` function from npm packages which will make a delay while the user types before making a request to the API.

```
const debounceDelay = 300;

const handleDebouncedChange = debounce((event) => {
    console.log('Debounced value:', event.target.value);
}, debounceDelay);

<input
    type="text"
    onChange={(e) => handleDebouncedChange(e)}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here is another way you can understand how debouncing works, here the state will be set 5 mili seconds late after the user stop typing.**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const DebouncedInput = () => {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState('');
  const [debouncedValue, setDebouncedValue] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    const delayDebounceFn = setTimeout(() => {
      setDebouncedValue(inputValue);
    }, 500);

    return () => clearTimeout(delayDebounceFn);
  }, [inputValue]);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setInputValue(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        value={inputValue}
        onChange={handleChange}
        placeholder="Type something..."
      />
      <p>Debounced value: {debouncedValue}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default DebouncedInput;
```